# Get Cairo output stream content when using PyCairo/CairoSharp/Inkscape

Tags: cairo, inkscape, pycairo

Throughout the Cairo source, there are various statements like:

```
_cairo_output_stream_printf (ctx->stream, "~> %f %f <~", ix, iy);
```

Is it possible to get the output stream contents to print to console or a file when using a Cairo wrapper or something that uses Cairo (e.g. PyCairo, CairoSharp, Inkscape). Being able to get this information when using Inkscape from the command line would be particularly wonderful. Having to modify the Inkscape source and build from that would be fine so long as the changes aren't too complex.

Thanks.

Comment: Uhm, what information would you want from that stream exactly? If I understand this correctly, you can just have inkspace print to/expert a PDF or PS file. The resulting file will be generated through those cairo functions...?

Comment: Specifically, the x, y, and character information on each individual text glyph. I'm no longer interested in doing this with Cairo, however.